# C#: SQL "Select Top.." query does not return any rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

I need to:

**1) Filter Rows by "NodeParent" (which I provide)**

**2) Sort rows by "Time" and get the most recent entry**

Here's what I wrote:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 NodeID FROM ActivityTable WHERE NodeParent='" + nodeid_previous + "'" + " ORDER BY Time DESC", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
             while (rdr.Read())
             {
                     nodeid_previous = rdr["NodeID"].ToString();
                     break;
             }
             rdr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
             //so on and so forth..
        }
}
```

This however doesn't return any results even though I HAVE rows which abide by these conditions. Is the query correct folks? :)

Comment: No.  `top` is not a MySQL construct.  Use `limit`.

Comment: instead of Top i should replace it with limit? @GordonLinoff

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NodeID FROM ActivityTable WHERE NodeParent='" + nodeid_previous + "' ORDER BY Time DESC Limit 1", con);`

Comment: You're using a SqlCommand so Top is correct. Limit is for MySql which, from your code, is clearly not what you are using. If you aren't getting results, try to debug and set a breakpoint at your cmd so you can at least see what it is the string actually evaluates to. Then run that against your db to ensure you're getting the results you think you should be. Your query that is being passed could be off in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before**

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 NodeID FROM ActivityTable WHERE NodeParent='" + nodeid_previous + "'" + " ORDER BY Time DESC", con);
```

**After** - Limit is added to the end of your query, rather than in the beginning of you select list like MS SQL Server's Top command

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NodeID FROM ActivityTable WHERE NodeParent='" + nodeid_previous + "'" + " ORDER BY Time DESC Limit 1", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Limit 1" in the end. There is no "TOP 1" in MYSQL. I guess it is SQLServer command.

Do:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NodeID FROM ActivityTable WHERE NodeParent='" + nodeid_previous + "'" + " ORDER BY Time DESC Limit 1", con);
```